# Escaping Quotes & other special characters to get HTML Encoded string in Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, html-encode

I have Excel cells that contain Newlines, Quotes & few more special characters. I wrote a formula in the last column which is a MySQL INSERT statement. When I execute the SQL statement, it shows errors as the data in these cells could not be processed well. I am thinking if there is a way to convert the cell string to html encoded string so that I will not have problems during the bulk MySQL INSERT.

A sample row has the following cell values :-

```
Cell 1 : ABCD Bank

Cell 2 : XYZ Branch

Cell 3 : #1234
"Boulevard Street",
City Name,State,Country

And in Cell 4, I have a formula that gives me an INSERT query like this :
="INSERT INTO table VALUES("""&Cell1&""","""&Cell2&""","""&Cell3&""");"
```

If you observe Cell3, it has newlines and quotes. And the query generated from Cell4 of that row gives an error while inserting into MySQL. So, I manually had to replace the quotes with empty string, substitute newline with empty string etc. Instead of doing such hard coding, is there a way to just do a html encode atleast to reduce the time of manually replacing the quotes and other such entities(if not newlines)? I am dealing with many sheets.

Comment: An example would be good?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Why not create a simple formula in cell 4 to replace the quotes and newline with empty string and then on Cell 5 the Insert statement? You can use `SUBSTITUE` formula

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well I did exactly the same thing and posted in the question also. I am searching for a better way of doing it.

Comment: Better way in the sense? VBA Code?